# how to get notification counter on every change in db

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

here i use sql dependancy method for changeing db:
    1. i want get notification counter like fb on every change in db

```
  public static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
           {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {


                 SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
                 sqlDep.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
                //  string message="added";
               GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
                 context.Clients.All.notify("added");
                // from here we will send notification message to client


            }


        }
```

here is my jquery code where i want to get notification counter:

but code is not working and string value is not handled from sqldependancy method.

```
$(function()
              {


              // Proxy created on the fly
              var job = $.connection.myHub;

              // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
              job.client.notify = function (message) {
                // 

                if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
                      updateNotificationCount();
                   }

              };
              // Start the connection

                $.connection.hub.start();
                updateNotificationCount();
          });    


              function updateNotificationCount() {
                  var count = 10;
                  count = parseInt($('#noti_Counter').html()) || 0;
                  count++;
                  $('#noti_Counter')
              .css({ opacity: 0 })
              .text(function () {
                  return "" + count + "";
              })
                   // ADD DYNAMIC VALUE (YOU CAN EXTRACT DATA FROM DATABASE OR XML).
              .css({ top: '-10px' })
               //.append('' + count + '')
              .animate({ top: '-2px', opacity: 1 }, 500);
              }
```

Comment: *"not working"* is a virtually useless problem statement ... especially when you present both client side and server side code and no debugging details. Take some time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: i just want to know how to pass data from server to client using signalR.your comment is not helpful.